# c# regular expression for finding links in <a> with specific ending

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex pattern for finding links in a string (with HTML code) to get the links with file endings like .gif or .png

Example String:

```
<a href="//site.com/folder/picture.png" target="_blank">picture.png</a>
```

For now I get everything between the " " and the text between the `<a>` and `</a>`.

I want to get this:

Href = `//site.com/folder/picture.png`
String = `picture.png`

My code so far:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace downloader
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = textBox1.Text;
        string s = gethtmlcode(url);
        foreach (LinkItem i in LinkFinder.Find(s))
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += Convert.ToString(i);
        }

    }


    static string gethtmlcode(string url)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            string htmlCode = client.DownloadString(url);
            return htmlCode;
        }
    }

    public struct LinkItem
    {
        public string Href;
        public string Text;
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Href + "\n\t" + Text + "\n\t";
        }
    }
    static class LinkFinder
    {
        public static List<LinkItem> Find(string file)
        {
            List<LinkItem> list = new List<LinkItem>();

            // 1.
            // Find all matches in file.
            MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(file, @"(<a.*?>.*?</a>)",
                RegexOptions.Singleline);

            // 2.
            // Loop over each match.
            foreach (Match m in m1)
            {
                string value = m.Groups[1].Value;
                LinkItem i = new LinkItem();

                // 3.
                // Get href attribute.
                Match m2 = Regex.Match(value, @"href=\""(.*?)\""",
                RegexOptions.Singleline);
                if (m2.Success)
                {
                    i.Href = m2.Groups[1].Value;
                }

                // 4.
                // Remove inner tags from text.
                string t = Regex.Replace(value, @"\s*<.*?>\s*", "",
                RegexOptions.Singleline);
                i.Text = t;

                list.Add(i);
            }
            return list;
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but have you considered, say, HtmlAgilityPack? Or any other HTML parsing library? It will make the code much easier to read, use and maintain.

Comment: [Do not parse HTML with Regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: a coupe of things here:

1.  You should tell us what actually does happen when you run that code.
2.  Regular Expressions aren't very good at parsing html.  You should look for an html parser.

Comment: I'm trying to make my first steps so I'm not very familiar and good with everything c# offers, sorry.

I've got a form with a richtextbox, a textbox and a button.
1. I insert the link into the text box
2. Press the button and the html code is loaded into a string
3. it runs the shown method (I'll edit the OP so the whole code will be there)
4. Show the Links with Texts in the richtextbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest using **HtmlAgilityPack** for this task. Install using *Manage NuGet Packages for Solution* menu, and add the following method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Collects a href attribute values and a node values if image extension is jpg or png
/// </summary>
/// <param name="html">HTML string or an URL</param>
/// <returns>A key-value pair list of href values and a node values</returns>
private List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetLinksWithHtmlAgilityPack(string html)
{
    var result = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hap;
    Uri uriResult;
    if (Uri.TryCreate(html, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult) && uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp)
    { // html is a URL 
        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
        hap = doc.Load(uriResult.AbsoluteUri);
    }
    else
    { // html is a string
        hap = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        hap.LoadHtml(html);
    }
    var nodes = hap.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");
    if (nodes != null)
        foreach (var node in nodes)
            if (Path.GetExtension(node.InnerText.Trim()).ToLower() == ".png" ||
                    Path.GetExtension(node.InnerText.Trim()).ToLower() == ".jpg")
            result.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>(node.GetAttributeValue("href", null), node.InnerText));
    return result;
}
```

Then, use it as (I am using a dummy string, just for demo)

```
var result = GetLinksWithHtmlAgilityPack("<a href=\"//site.com/folder/picture.png\" target=\"_blank\">picture.png</a><a href=\"//site.com/folder/picture.bmp\" target=\"_blank\">picture.bmp</a>");
```

Output:

[image]

Or, with a URL, something like:

```
var result = GetLinksWithHtmlAgilityPack("http://www.google.com");
```