# Regex - Single quotes OR Double quotes -C#

Tags: c#, regex, double-quotes, single-quotes

How to change this:

```
Regex.Match(value, @"href=\""(.*?)\""",RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

So that it will select href='foobar' (Single quotes ') AS well as selecting href="foobar" (Double quotes ")??

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30659022/regex-for-extract-url-from-string-fails-when-string-contains-multiple-double-quo). The regex in the question should work for you.

Comment: Do you specifically only want to select href='foobar'   ?

Comment: If you want to parse out a href links from HTML, see a [snippet here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629793/c-sharp-regular-expression-for-finding-links-in-a-with-specific-ending) showing how you can do that with HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: I tried installing the HtmlAgilityPack earlier in the day Wiktor via NuGet, however when installing it just said "Cannot install, Corrupted data" or something similar

Comment: I have not had any trouble. You can retry later. If you want I can post my answer describing how to use HtmlAgilityPack to get the `href`s.

Comment: It is okay, thank you very much for your help though Wiktor ^_^ 
I will retry, but I will probably not have need for htmlagility after this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pattern like this:

```
href=(["'])(.*?)\1
```

This will match any string of that contains `href=` followed by a `"` or `'` followed by any number of characters (non-greedily) followed by the same character that was matched previously in group 1. Note that `\1` is a [backreference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwdfzxy(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also note that this will also mean the contents of your attribute will be captured in group 2 rather than group 1.

Now, the correct way to escape this [string literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx) would be either like this (using regular strings):

```
Regex.Match(value, "href=([\"'])(.*?)\\1", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Or like this (using verbatim strings):

```
Regex.Match(value, @"href=([""'])(.*?)\1", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: @SamHoole : Remember to mark this as the accepted answer by pressing the green check mark on the left of the post.